# Is there a way to check if two Jupyter iPython widgets are already linked?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am trying to detect if two widgets that I have created (a `widgets.Text` field and a `widgets.SelectMultiple` Field) are already linked without creating a separate `boolean` variable to keep track, as that can get messy.  I wasn't sure if there is a built-in method like `<my_widget>.isLinked` already available?  I haven't found anything outside of the `link`/`unlink` for handling this. I also have not looked at the Link object that is returned, but not sure if that will help me in this case.

I have a `widgets.SelectMultiple` list, that I will call the selection field, that contains over a hundred different entries.  To keep track of the items that the user has selected, I have a separate `widgets.Text` box that stores the results.  I have linked these two widgets so that when items are selected, they appear in the results field. When these items are `link`-ed, everything's great and synced up.  However, there are instances where I'm going to `unlink` the widgets.  For example, I have a custom `widgets.Text` search field that shrinks the list in the `widgets.SelectMultiple` based on user input to narrow down the results.  During the state of the user interacting with the search field, I want to `unlink` so I don't have any exceptions thrown, and then `link` again once the user has completed their search and chosen their item. At any point, the user can also choose to mouse-select an entry, even if they are in the middle of a search, so this is why I would like to check if we are linked or not (will need to manually add it to the `widgets.values` list of the results field if `unlink`-ed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I should have just dug a little deeper.  The Link object returned is exactly what I need. It returns None if the link is non-existent, so I can just use that.  Thanks for entertaining me Stack Overflow...